# Get MAC Address in react-nativr MacOS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a desktop app for osX that will use a few employees. The distribution will be offline. The desktop app needs the MAC address. As far as I have searched things did not work for me. Can anyone tell me if is it possible or not? if possible then how can we do it?

Project Info -

```
"react-native": "0.62.0",
 "react-native-macos": "^0.62.22"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use [`getmac`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/getmac).

```
import getMAC from 'getmac'
 
console.log(getMAC()) // prints e4:ce:8f:5b:a7:fc
```

Comment: It's not working. Through some 'OS' package error. If I install OS npm package then it shows another error.